# utf-8' codec can't encode character '\\udcf3'

Tags: python, aiohttp

I have a problem with the library autodynatrace and oneagent
I am using aiohttp with fastapi, when I make a request to a external service, I get this error: utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcf3'

This is the error complete:

Exception in ASGI application 2023-11-16T17:52:13.500560145Z Traceback (most recent call last): 2023-11-16T17:52:13.500568875Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 428, in run_asgi 2023-11-16T17:52:13.500574755Z result = await app( # type: ignore[func-returns-value] 2023-11-16T17:52:13.500579185Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.500583755Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in **call** 2023-11-16T17:52:13.500588685Z return await self.app(scope, receive, send) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.500593565Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.500598285Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 284, in **call** 2023-11-16T17:52:13.500602915Z await super().**call**(scope, receive, send) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.500608185Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in **call** 2023-11-16T17:52:13.500612805Z await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.500617065Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in **call** 2023-11-16T17:52:13.500693755Z raise exc
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in **call** 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501033275Z await self.app(scope, receive, _send) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501038645Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autodynatrace/wrappers/fastapi/middleware.py", line 56, in **call**
return await self.app(scope, receive, wrapped_send) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501062025Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501065835Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in **call** 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501069395Z raise exc 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501073585Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in **call** 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501078315Z await self.app(scope, receive, sender) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501082665Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in **call** 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501087345Z raise e 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501091945Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in **call** 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501095925Z await self.app(scope, receive, send) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501099785Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in **call** 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501103455Z await route.handle(scope, receive, send) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501107035Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501110695Z await self.app(scope, receive, send)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501120175Z response = await func(request) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501125245Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501130415Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 241, in app 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501135275Z raw_response = await run_endpoint_function( 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501139625Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501143695Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autodynatrace/wrappers/fastapi/wrapper.py", line 27, in session_init_dynatrace 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501147435Z return await wrapped(*args, **kwargs) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501151075Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501154985Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 169, in run_endpoint_function 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501159795Z return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501168875Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501173085Z return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501177715Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501182605Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501187475Z return await get_async_backend().run_sync_in_worker_thread( 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501192485Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501251825Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 2106, in run_sync_in_worker_thread 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501259715Z return await future 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501263645Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501267475Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 833, in run 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501292495Z result = context.run(func, *args) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501298175Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501302625Z File "/src/worker/infrastructure/worker_routes.py", line 58, in get_products 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501315215Z return WorkerController.get_products(input_data) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501320075Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501324505Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autodynatrace/wrappers/custom/wrapper.py", line 78, in wrapper 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501329205Z return wrapped(*args, **kwargs) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501336065Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501357135Z File "/src/worker/infrastructure/worker_controller.py", line 38, in get_products 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501362865Z response = usecase.execute(input_data) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501366695Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501370415Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autodynatrace/wrappers/custom/wrapper.py", line 78, in wrapper 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501373945Z return wrapped(*args, **kwargs) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501377715Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501381855Z File "/src/worker/application/usecases/get_products_usecase.py", line 36, in execute 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501386505Z response = self._get_response() 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501390125Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501393815Z File "/src/worker/application/usecases/get_products_usecase.py", line 47, in _get_response 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501397525Z return self._verify_type_product(type_product) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501402375Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501407045Z File "/src/worker/application/usecases/get_products_usecase.py", line 78, in _verify_type_product 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501411435Z return self._combo_products() 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501416345Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/src/worker/application/usecases/get_products_usecase.py", line 81, in _combo_products 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501425695Z combo_products = self._identify_combo_product_info() 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501430075Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501434425Z File "/src/worker/application/usecases/get_products_usecase.py", line 92, in _identify_combo_product_info 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501438505Z response = asyncio.run(response) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501442035Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501445845Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501449625Z return runner.run(main) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501453535Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501458135Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501463185Z return self._loop.run_until_complete(task) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501467415Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501471145Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501475065Z return future.result() 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501479645Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501484205Z File "/src/shared/infrastructure/general_request.py", line 35, in get 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501488815Z async with session.get(url, headers=self.headers, params=query_params) as response: 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501493545Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1167, in **aenter** 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501498275Z self._resp = await self._coro 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501503225Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501510085Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/autodynatrace/wrappers/aiohttp/wrapper.py", line 26, in dynatrace_request 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501522225Z tracer.add_response_headers(dict(response.headers)) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501526385Z File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/oneagent/sdk/tracers.py", line 247, in add_kvs_fn 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501531195Z add_kvs_impl( 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501535655Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/oneagent/_impl/native/sdkctypesiface.py", line 672, in headerlist_fn
val_arr[i] = CCString.from_param(value) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501543735Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501547795Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/oneagent/_impl/native/sdkctypesiface.py", line 82, in from_param 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501552545Z return cls.from_unicode(pystr) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501557775Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501562465Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/oneagent/_impl/native/sdkctypesiface.py", line 100, in from_unicode 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501567285Z return cls.from_u8_bytes(str_to_u8(pyustr)) 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501571945Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 2023-11-16T17:52:13.501577205Z UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcf3' in position 28: surrogates not allowed

This is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG7ju.png)

Can you help me? I uninstall the libraries and my project works good

Comment: You should copy and paste the code here, along with the full error trace. This doesn't show which line in your code raises the error.

Comment: listo amigo, se actualizo

Comment: i have copied and pasted the full core, my code is an image

Comment: Your code should ***not*** be an image. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).